# Is there any way to get only part of a match with regex?

Tags: regex

If I apply `/a(b|c)/g` to "ab ac ad" it would match "ab" and "ac", but I need only the "a". I don't want the "a" inside "ad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you do not need a *capturing group*, you need a *lookahead*:

```
/a(?=b|c)/g
```

See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xR6hI6/2)

```js
console.log("abc\nacd".match(/a(?=b|c)/g));
```

Lookaheads only check if a string matches the pattern, but return *true* or *false*, whether a match can be returned, or not (or whether to backtrack into the patter or not).

Another way is by using a capturing group on the pattern part that you need to obtain:

```
 /(a)(?:b|c)/g
```

And the data you need (`a`) will be in Group 1. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xR6hI6/3).

```js
var re = /(a)(?:b|c)/g; 
var str = 'abc\nacd';
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```